# Join a part of the array and leaving the rest as is in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array, and I want to join from some beginIndex to some endIndex, and leave the rest as is.

For example, I have this array:

```
['first', 'second', '<error>', 'Can not parse the third element', '</error>', 'fourth', 'fifth']
```

And I want to `join('\n')` the elements from index 2 until index 4. So that I get:

```
['first', 'second', '<error>\nCan not parse the third element\n</error>', 'fourth', 'fifth']
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: Wow, thanks for the 4 downvotes and 2 close votes for this innocent well formulated question. Yes, I got something that worked with a for of loop, but I found it ugly, and I was looking for something more elegant, I didn't know about the splice method. Thanks Soviut and Nina for the interesting answers. Hope that other people with the same question can learn from it as well...

Comment: My suggestion would be: "post your attempts in your question, explain where and how they failed." What did your attempts do wrong, what did they do that they should not have done, what didn't they do that they should have done? Were there any errors in your console (F12 in most browsers)? Please post your "*[mcve]*" in your question.

Comment: It seems you could do "get the subarray of elements 2 to 4, join them, and replace the original elements 2 to 4 with the single result". So the next step would be to hit the docs and find the functions that do this, then string them together into an attempted solution.

Comment: @DavidThomas I feel like my attempts would only give noise for readers with the same question ending up on this page. I was using a for of loop, which worked, after that I tried a bit with the reduce method, which worked as well, but not as elegant as I thought should be possible. I didn't know about splice method, which seems to be the most elegant way of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The **`splice()`** method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

```js
var array = ['first', 'second', '<error>', 'Can not parse the third element', '</error>', 'fourth', 'fifth'],
    beginIndex =2,
    endIndex = 4;

array.splice(beginIndex, 0, array.splice(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex + 1).join('\n'));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a subset of your array, join them, then [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) those values back into the array. Splicing allows elements to be deleted/replaced while you're also inserting.

```js
var logs = ['first', 'second', '<error>', 'Can not parse the third element', '</error>', 'fourth', 'fifth'];

var startIndex = 2;
var endIndex = 5;

var slicedTokens = logs.slice(startIndex, 5);
var joinedString = slicedTokens.join('');
var deleteCount = endIndex - startIndex;

logs.splice(startIndex, deleteCount, joinedString);

console.log(logs);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be:-

```
var a = ['first', 'second', '<error>', 'Can not parse the third element', '</error>', 'fourth', 'fifth'];

var b = [];
var startJoinIndex = 2;
var endJoinIndex = 4;
var joinedValue = "";
a.forEach(function(item, index){
    if (index >= startJoinIndex && index <= endJoinIndex){
    joinedValue += item;
    if (index === endJoinIndex){
      b.push(joinedValue);
    }
  } else {
    b.push(item);
  }
});

console.log(b);
```